# suppose we have this construction in Express.js project

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose we have this construction in Express.js project. which of the following paths will match this route?

```
app.get('/kleen',function (req,res) { return res.send('kllan'); }};
```

Comment: which are "the following paths" ?

Comment: GET - http://<your-domain>/kleen
refer - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: -Klmn
-kllmn
-kleen
-klen

Comment: only `GET - http://<your-domain>/kleen` will match and the route is case insensitive.